# Помогите разобраться с enum TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Всем привет. Я пишу приложение на react + typescript. И, я сделал хук, который возвращает мне роуты для меня с определенным именем. У меня есть enum Menus, в котором содержать названия всех меню. И, когда я вызываю метод для получения массива нужных мне роутов, я хочу иметь подсказки в виде строк( `useMenu(['<Вот тут>', '<Вот тут>'])` ). Подсказки появляются, но когда я пишу, допустим `useMenu(['user'])`, то оно подсвечивается как ошибка, а если `useMenu([Menus.User])`, то все норм. Но я хочу как-то использовать первый вариант. Есть ли вообще такая возможность?

```
export enum Menus {
Main = 'main',
User = 'user',
Admin = 'admin',
}

import {Menus, ROUTES} from "../appRouter";
import {IRoute} from "../appRouter/routes";


const useMenu = (names?: Menus[]): IRoute[] => {
    return !names ?
        ROUTES:
        ROUTES.filter(({menuName}) => menuName && names.includes(menuName));
}

export default useMenu;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `useMenu([Menus.User, Menus.Admin])`

Comment: не используй enum, а используй [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Получается, мне надо будет изменить мой `enum Menus` на `type Menus = 'user' | 'admin' | 'main';` ?

Comment: да, что-то вроде такого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enum` считаются отдельным типом. Поэтому им нельзя присваивать просто строки.

Если необходимо разрешить передавать ограниченное количество строк, можно воспользоваться [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html). Они представляют из себя [`union type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) из разрешенных значений, например:

```
'user' | 'admin' | 'main'
```